# How should titles like "P'tit Quinquin" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a question about the movie [P'tit Quinquin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%27tit_Quinquin_(film)): [Who is the murderer in p'tit quinquin or li'l quinquin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89380/who-is-the-murderer-in-ptit-quinquin-or-lil-quinquin)

I wanted to add the appropriate tag, but I'm not sure whether it should be `ptit-quinquin` or `p-tit-quinquin`.

Is there any guidance WRT how titles featuring such special characters should be handled?

Comment: Or we have to go with US title ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma that's fighting symptoms. What if the english title has special characters?

Comment: Can't put an apostrophe in tags? Why not? Fix that and you win the entire war, not just this battle.

Comment: Meh, what next? Exclamation marks, colons and question marks? The lack of punctuation support in tags also has the advantage of reducing ambiguity in tagging and the danger of duplicate tags. Tags will *always* be just an abstraction/approximation of the actual title and their simplicity comes with a certain structural beauty.

Comment: Exclamation marks? Yes. E.g., *Happy!*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, p'tit is an abbrev of petit. It seems weird to replace the apostrophe with a space, because that suggests they are two words.

As such, I would suggest going with [ptit-quinquin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ptit-quinquin).

The same would apply to the title of the related English show: [Li'l Quinquin](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3053694/). Here I would suggest [lil-quinquin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lil-quinquin).

Comment: i think this makes the most sense